# Can we send tokens to BSC pair address and receive tokens in return?

Tags: tokens, nodejs, bsc, sendtransaction, router

We're almost at war with ChatGPT :)

For example, when we send 1 busd to a pair address, such as BUSD/WBNB, won't the pair address directly give us WBNB in return?

Chatgpt says it gives one, it doesn't give one, but in some TX records I reviewed, this is possible. Someone sends BUSD directly to the trading pair through a contract and receives WBNB in return.

For example: https://bscscan.com/tx/0x8046d2f6cdc73c1437278aff62b6d292cdfb0094602a14444bfb5b89baea6b8f